# How to get async data from component using Helmet?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, meta-tags, react-helmet

I want to generate dynamic meta tags in my React app. I'm using Helmet and have a problem because it is empty after calling Helmet.renderStatic(). 
My index.js file:

```html
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
console.log('meta', helmet.meta.toString());

registerServiceWorker();
```

and my component looks like that:

```html
  public render() {
    const { article } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="article-published">
          <Helmet>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
             <meta property="og:title" content={article.title} />
          </Helmet>
```

The problem is that I'm calling API to get article, so when I get a helmet in my index.js article is not there yet, so my helmet.meta has no content.

How can I make it wait for the article to be received from API to use it in the title?

Comment: You can just use `<Helmet>{ article.title && <title>{article.title}</title> }</Helmet>` and `react-helmet` will update your page's title automatically.

Comment: @vedsmith92 after writing `{ article.title && <title>{article.title}</title> }` in my component I always get the title empty when printing, like this:  `<title data-react-helmet="true"></title>`. But if I put normal string like this: `<title>Qwerty</title>` it works. So it seems like it's not being updated...